# Automatically install build dependencies prior to building an RPM package

Tags: fedora, rpmbuild

I am trying to build a .rpm package. I have just followed the steps to do that. Till now all steps were gone fine but now i just stuck with this step. I just ran the following command and got this error:

`rpmbuild -ba asterisk.spec`

```
error: Failed build dependencies: 
    gtk2-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    libsrtp-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    [... more ...]
    freetds-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    uw-imap-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
```

I am using fedora-15. How to resolve this error?

How I do install all depencencies during installation of `src.rpm` package. Is it possible?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use the `yum-builddep` command from the `yum-utils` package to install all the build dependencies for a package.

The arguments can either be paths to spec files, paths to source RPMs or the names of packages which exist as source RPMs in a configured repository, for example:

```
yum-builddep my-package.spec
```

or

```
yum-builddep my-package.src.rpm
```

The same thing can be achieved on newer versions of Fedora that use `dnf` as their package manager by making sure that `dnf-plugins-core` is installed and then doing:

```
dnf builddep my-package.spec
```

or

```
dnf builddep my-package.src.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give me any example syntax for same or any relevant link?

Comment: I've already pretty much described how you run it! Beyond which your first stop, as for any linux command, would be `man yum-builddep` which will doubtless be enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

`yum-builddep` doesn't seem to work if the mirror you use doesn't serve source RPMs. This may not handle all cases, but it usually works for me:

```
sudo yum install -y $(<rpmbuild> | fgrep 'is needed by' | awk '{print $1}')
```

where `<rpmbuild>` is your `rpmbuild` command (e.g., `rpmbuild -ba foo.spec`).

Answer (score 0):

On PHP building - especially `phpbrew` I used `dnf builddep php`, it worked.