# how to build cascade dependences in spec?

Tags: nginx, dependencies, specifications, rpmbuild

Centos 7
trying to build nginx with devel `gcc-5.3.1.rpm`

manually goes

```
yum install centos-release-scl
```

only then

```
yum install devtoolset-4-gcc
```

how to add cascade installation of dependencies in spec rpmbuild?

```
BuildRequires: centos-release-scl
Requires: devtoolset-4-gcc
```

installs only first one
the same as here

```
BuildRequires: centos-release-scl
BuildRequires: devtoolset-4-gcc
```

> BuildRequires(pre): is not supported

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically install build dependencies prior to building an RPM package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227162/automatically-install-build-dependencies-prior-to-building-an-rpm-package)

Answer (score 1):

You have to list the prerequisite in both `Requires` and `BuildRequires` if it is truly needed both at build and runtime. If it is *only* used by a `pre` or `post` scriptlet, then you add the suffix to `Requires`. If all the scriptlets, build, and runtime need it, then you have to explicitly list it as needed *every* time. A contrived example where you *really* like an old editor:

```
Requires(pre): ed
Requires(post): ed
Requires(preun): ed
Requires(post): ed
Requires: ed
BuildRequires: ed
```

---

Edit: Re-reading question and comment on this answer, I think this is a dupe of "[Automatically install build dependencies prior to building an RPM package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13227162/836748)"

Comment: to clearify
gcc is needed here only for compiling
what in this situation should be written?

`code`
        BuildRequires: centos-release-scl
`code`

installs normaly

`code`
        Requires(pre): devtoolset-4-gcc
        Requires(post): devtoolset-4-gcc
        Requires(preun): devtoolset-4-gcc
        Requires(post): devtoolset-4-gcc
        Requires: devtoolset-4-gcc
        BuildRequires: devtoolset-4-gcc
`code`

just says no devtoolset-4-gcc is found inspite of auto installing

Comment: If it is only needed for building, then simply `BuildRequires` would work. However, `rpmbuild` is not `yum` - you need to manually install them before building, e.g. "`sudo yum install devtoolset-4-gcc`".

Comment: may be some script before building to pass into yum,,,, ?

Comment: Yes, it's called `yum-builddep` and I linked to it in my answer.